# Postgres - Sql - PgSql Cheatsheets

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, postgresql

I am developing some python queries using psycopg and I was looking for some good cheat sheet.

Which Postgres - Sql - PgSql Cheatsheets do you use regularly during DB development?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just use [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html), it's well written and comprehensive.

Comment: I want something just to check quickly the syntax, something that I can print

Comment: +1 for the manual. I think there are just too many SQL statements so that it could be printed properly

Answer (score 4):

The guys from Postgresonline.com made a couple of [cheatcheats](http://www.postgresonline.com/specials.php).

But nothing can beat the fine manual :-)